# Is it possible do disable showing the ASUS logo when booting the computer?

Tags: boot, bios

I have an ASUS laptop. I would like to disable showing the ASUS logo when starting the machine.

I checked out the BIOS settings but couldn't find anything related to that.

The only setting I found is: `POST Logo Type` that can be `Static` or `Animated`. If I select `Animated`, then the logo will appear with a fade in efect.

Is it possible do disable showing the ASUS logo when booting the computer?

Answer (score -1):

There are many different pc firmware softwares (BIOSes/UEFIs) on computers produced by ASUS which have different settings available. My very old asus motherbord does have a setting to switch on/of the logo but I can't tell it in your case.

Things I would suggest you to do:

- find the manual of your system and search the firmware section
- visit any page of your firmware menu and search for such an option

For one of my motherboards (not asus but similar bios (same vendor than asus bioses I know and has the same animated main bar)) for example you can find the required information at http://www.manualslib.com/manual/795186/Msi-Ms-7551.html on page 45